# Command executed during make won't work at command prompt

Tags: c++, qt

Can't post pictures, so here is the QT output when compiling a source for example:

```
14:04:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/daniel/SkyDrive/Files/Development/C++/ETH I/CUBLI Choreographer/build-CUBLIchoreographer-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'../CUBLIchoreographer' -I'.' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtWidgets' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtSerialPort' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtCore' -I'debug' -I'.' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/win32-g++'  -o debug/mainwindow.o ../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.cpp
../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.cpp: In member function 'int MainWindow::addTimeline()':
../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.cpp:34:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

the above is successful, yet when copy pasting the relevant command into cmd this is the result:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\daniel>workbench C++

C:\Users\daniel\SkyDrive\Files\Development\C++>cd "ETH I"

C:\Users\daniel\SkyDrive\Files\Development\C++\ETH I>cd "CUBLI Choreographer"

C:\Users\daniel\SkyDrive\Files\Development\C++\ETH I\CUBLI Choreographer>cd build-CUBLIchoreographer-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug

C:\Users\daniel\SkyDrive\Files\Development\C++\ETH I\CUBLI Choreographer\build-CUBLIchoreographer-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug>g++ -c -pipe -fno-ke
ep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_Q
MAIN -I'../CUBLIchoreographer' -I'.' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtWidgets' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtGui
' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtSerialPort' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtCore' -I'debug' -I'.' -I'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/mkspecs/win32-g++'  -o
 debug/mainwindow.o ../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.cpp
In file included from ../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.cpp:1:0:
../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.h:4:23: fatal error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory
 #include <QMainWindow>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

(I've checked, and the QMainWindow class is present in 'C:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtWidgets' which is part of the includes)

I feel silly for asking, thanks in advance.

Note: I face this problem because I need to know which compile flags are necessary for the YouCompleteMe plugin in vim. When copying those of the above command, the QMainWindow class is similarly not recognized.

Comment: The command you see echoed to the terminal is likely being run from another directory.

Comment: Thanks for making me double check, and - correct me if I'm wrong - isn't
"Entering directory 'C:/Users/daniel/SkyDrive/Files/Development/C++/ETH I/CUBLI Choreographer/build-CUBLIchoreographer-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug' "

and

'
C:\Users\daniel\SkyDrive\Files\Development\C++\ETH I\CUBLI Choreographer\build-CUBLIchoreographer-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug>' equivalent?

As well, the include error is referred to with an absolute path

Comment: `../CUBLIchoreographer/mainwindow.h` is a relative path.